# app engine fails to deploy app with large dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

So i built an app using machine learning on a small pandas dataframe, ~1000 records. I use gcloud app deploy, it hosts on appspot and I am able to use it.

I increase the dataframe to ~30,000 records and the app still runs on my local. When i use gcloud app deploy, i get a 500 server error. I am loading the dataframe from a csv in my project root.

My app.yaml looks like:

```
runtime: python37
service: snow
instance_class: F4_1G
```

From another stackoverflow post, I switched the instance_class to F4_1G but it keeps having the same error. I also tried

```
gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1000
```

Any other ideas on what could cause app engine to have this error?

Comment: Error 500 typically means your program crashed or failed to start. What messages are in Stackdriver?

Comment: ah found it. it says "exceeded soft memory limit of 2048 mb, consider increasing in app yaml file".... how do I increase this in app yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

> "exceeded soft memory limit of 2048 mb, consider increasing in app yaml file"

Indicates that your instance class has run out of memory, in theory would be able to increase the memory by specifying another instance class, however you are already using the one with the most memory (2048mb). Check the list of [instance classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes).

So in your case, the solution would be to change to [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart), and to do so you will need to specify something like this on your **app.yaml**:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2.1 
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

On **memory_gb** you specify the memory that the vm instance will use, and here's the formula to know which value to set:

> memory_gb = cpu * [0.9 - 6.5] - 0.4

You choose the desired memory from the interval [0.9 - 6.5], multiply it by the number of CPUs and subtract 0.4. For a more extend explanation check the [app.yaml reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings).

Also, check the [App Engine Pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances) to know how your billing will change from Standard to Flex.